# how to clear a div consist of multiple charts to show another chart

Tags: jquery

i have a div which im using it for different charts,i also have 3 different button which supposed to show new chart on click:

```
  <div id="chartsGridsContainer">
  <div id="grid1"></div>
  <div id="grid2"></div>
  <div id="chart1"></div>
  <div id="chart2"></div>
  </div>
```

here is my button:

```
  <input type="button" id="btn1" />
  <input type="button" id="btn1" />
  <input type="button" id="btn1" />
```

The problem is when I want to click on btn1 I want the above main div to be cleared and show the following grid,but if I use empty() method,it will not show
anything in the div:

```
 if(("#btn1").click(function(){


$("#chartsGridsContainer").empty();


          $("#chart1").kendoGrid({
                            scrollable: true,
                            height: 250,
                                    dataSource: {
                                    data: rslt,


                        },

                                    columns: [{

                                    field: "TurbineName",
                                    title: "Turbine",

                                }, {
                                    field: "windSpeed",
                                    title: "Wind Speed(Km/h)"
                                }, {
                                    field: "Avalability",
                                    title: "Avalaibility(%)"
                                }]
                                });


                                }

                        }

                             });



   }));
```

im looking for a method other than empty() or hide(),to clear the div if there is any other grid or chart,to show the grid on my btn1 button

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid( { /* configuration */ } ); // create a Grid widget

$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").destroy(); // destroy the Grid

$("#grid").empty(); // empty the Grid content (inner HTML)
// or
$("#grid").remove(); // remove all Grid HTML
```

Since you are using kendo lib use its function to clear chart instead of manually doing it. please check this link https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/destroy

Comment: which one should I use ?I want to remove it and show new one,empty or remove?

Comment: @papagallo To properly destroy widgets created declaratively through the Kendo UI MVVM mechanism, first use the kendo.unbind() method to remove any MVVM bindings related to the widget, and then call kendo.destroy() for the appropriate container, or the destroy() method of each widget inside this container.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to empty parent div:

```
$("#chartsGridsContainer").empty();
```

And then right after that you are calling:

```
$("#chart1").kendoGrid({ ...})
```

on the div that is deleted with empty option.

You should clear like this:

```
$("#chartsGridsContainer div").empty();
```

This will clear all the divs inside container.

After that you can do the rest:

```
$("#chart1").kendoGrid({
                            scrollable: true,
                            height: 250,
                                    dataSource: {
                                    data: rslt,


                        },

                                    columns: [{

                                    field: "TurbineName",
                                    title: "Turbine",

                                }, {
                                    field: "windSpeed",
                                    title: "Wind Speed(Km/h)"
                                }, {
                                    field: "Avalability",
                                    title: "Avalaibility(%)"
                                }]
                                });


                                }

                        }

                             });
```